# How / where does one define AudioWorkletProcessor

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audioworkletprocessor

I have just started playing with the Web Audio API.  I have been pouring over the API docs and see several examples.  My issue is probably trivial and I am probably missing something fundamental.

I have the worker javascript file below. It came from an example whoes URL I have misplaced. I am using PyCharm as my IDE, if that matters, and it flags "AudioWorkletProcessor" as undefined. I have looked at a lot of pages at this point and I do not see any import or require statements that might define this interface.

I have just tried running the code in Firefox and Chrome and both throw exceptions on the undefined `AudioWorkletProcessor` line.

Should this be a "builtin"?  Is it part of a library/module that I just haven't seen referenced yet?

```
class AudioRecorder extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    static get parameterDescriptors() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'isRecording',
                defaultValue: 0,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 1,
            },
        ]
    }

    process(inputs, outputs, parameters) {
        const buffer = []
        const channel = 0

        for (let t = 0; t < inputs[0][channel].length; t += 1) {
            if (parameters.isRecording[0] === 1) { // <2>
                buffer.push(inputs[0][channel][t])
            }
        }

        if (buffer.length >= 1) {
            this.port.postMessage({buffer})
        }

        return true
    }
}

registerProcessor('audio-recorder', AudioRecorder)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AudioWorkletProcessor` base class and the `registerProcessor()` function are both available as globals in the [`AudioWorkletGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletGlobalScope).

It's not possible to evaluate that code in the console. You need to load your JavaScript file like that:

```
audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('path/to/your/file.js');
```

I guess your IDE is just not aware of the fact that you are editing something that is meant to be evaluated in that scope.

Comment: Yes, probably ignore the IDE in this.  When I deploy the test to a web server the app throws an exception because AudioWorkletProcessor  is not defined.

Comment: Are you loading your file on the main thread or as described above with `audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule()`?

Comment: Thank you! I am using `addModule()`. 

I was trying different path strings and URL parts with `addModule()` to point to the "AudioRecorder" file and finally discovered a simple typo on my part. All is well now.  Thanks for having me look again at a thing I have looked at 10k times already.